# Extra characters added to str.match() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

When doing an...

```
var URLPattern = '^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?';
alert(str.match(URLPattern));
```

it will match a URL correctly but then append

```
,ht,,m,,,,
```

to the end of the url

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Use [non-capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out what [`.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns: an array consisting of the match and the matched [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Use

```
var result = str.match(URLPattern);
alert(result != null ? result[0] : "nothing found");
```

Btw, your regex is improperly constructed. Use a [regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression) instead of that string literal which eats your backslashes:

```
var URLPattern = /^(ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*(:(0-9)*)*(\/?)([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\?\,\'\/\\\+&amp;%\$#_]*)?/;
```